# CI 'ng build' can't find typescript files while local build can

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have a relatively big project which is running on Angular 7.3.8. I've been developing for a long time without any problems. Upon trying to integrate CI/CD I got errors on the `ng build --prod` command. Same errors exist for `ng build` command.

I've tried changing the `compilerOptions.baseUrl` and change all import statements accordingly, sadly none has helped. I've also added the correct cli version to the package.json to make sure it wasn't an error because of a newer version. As you can see in the screenshot I'm getting the error on Angular version 7.3.8.

How can I fix this?

[image: error]

Comment: in your ci/cd are you doing an npm install before building?

Comment: Yes, that's where the angular version also gets installed.

Comment: oh sorry it was hard to read what was missing from the image. All of the visible errors seem to be stemming from the models folder? is that true? Is it included in the repo your ci/cd tool is drawing from?

Comment: The models folder is in a submodule of the repository where this pipeline runs. The submodules are loaded so the models folder should definitely be there.

Comment: Would you please replace your image of an exception with text? It makes it easier to read, and is better [for several reasons](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofanexception/). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've not found the issue, but found a fix.

My Azure pipeline was running on a ubuntu (virtual) machine. I think something with all the paths need to change in order to make it work on Linux. Debugging in the pipeline is a pain so I'll probably need to set up some Linux machine and test building my project over there first.

For now I've changed me VM to a Windows server, which builds just fine without any additional configuration.

Comment: I have hd similar issue earlier this week where issue was that I had baseUrl or basePath missing and so vs code was doing absolute imports instead of relative to file.from the above logs it looks like you also have something similar going on with admin-panel-quiz-component. Try replacing any imports starting with ‘src/path-to-file‘ to relative like ‘.../path-to-file’.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!